# IBM db2 union query bad results

Tags: db2, union

When I execute this query in SQL Server which calls to IBM,

```
Select * from openquery(ibm,'
                        Select COST_AMT,'Query1' as Query 
                           from table
                           where clause 
                           with ur;
')
union
Select * from openquery(ibm,'
                           Select COST_AMT,'Query2' as Query 
                           from table
                           different where clause 
                           with ur;
')
```

I get different results in the union query than when I execute them separately and bring the results in together.  I have tried the union query inside the openquery so I believe this is an IBM thing. The results appear to be a distinct selection of `COST_AMT` sorted by lowest to highest.

ie:

```
1,Query1
2,Query1
3,Query1
1,Query2
2,Query2
3,Query2
```

but the data is actually like this:

```
1,Query1
1,Query1
1,Query1
2,Query1
2,Query1
3,Query1
1,Query2
1,Query2
1,Query2
2,Query2
2,Query2
3,Query1
```

Am I missing something about the ibm union query? I realize I could sum and get the answer, (which is what I plan no doing) but I want to know more about *why* this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "ibm" or "db2" -- the SQL UNION operator removes duplicates. To retain duplicates use UNION ALL.